# PHP skip if the text field is empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form that UPDATES columns in a table, but if a text field in the form is empty, it also blanks out the column in database. Here is ghostbined code of my current script:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/jd9b9

Basically, I want it so that if the field is empty, it is either ignored or not submitted or skipped.

Thanks!

Comment: Might pay to share the first lines of code here instead of linking externally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (!empty($_POST))` checks to see if your post array contains any data at all, which means every insert statement will trigger, if there is even *one* field set in your post array. Instead, you need to check each individual field to see if it is set, and if it has a value you're interested in (ie, not an empty string). Or in other words:

change `if (!empty($_POST)) {` to `if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != '') {`

for each of your insert statements, and the appropriate `$_POST` key (username, description, etc)

**for completeness**
Apparently, `empty($_POST['username'])` will also work, as opposed to the `isset` and subsequent check. Thanks to comments

Comment: Or specify each field in the not empty, `if(!empty($_POST['username']))`

Comment: you sure with the condition

Comment: ops i thought its $_POST['username'] == ''.nvm

Comment: That does the job! I cannot vote up so I am forced to say thanks here in the comments!!!

Comment: @chris85 hm. i'm sure at some stage `empty()` used to complain about undefined indexes if they weren't also set

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you're just checking if `$_POST` is not empty, then setting each individual value. So if you enter a value in one field, all others will get updated too.

You can consolidate your "setting data" code a little bit.

Try the following:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $toUpdate = array();
    // Loop through each of your values...
    foreach (array('username', 'description', 'userdescription', 'heading', 'subheading', 'subheading2') as $field) {
        // Check individual values are not empty and also not full of spaces
        if (!empty($_POST[$field]) && trim($_POST[$field]) !== '') {
            // Build some SQL additions
            $toUpdate[] = $field . ' = ' . $link->real_escape_string(trim($_POST[$field]));
        }
    }
    if (!empty($toUpdate)) {
        // Perform one single update query
        $link->query("UPDATE firstsection SET " . implode(', ', $toUpdate) . " WHERE id = 2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this :

```
if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $link->query("UPDATE firstsection SET username = '".$link->real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' WHERE id = 2");
}
if (!empty($_POST['description'])) {
    $link->query("UPDATE firstsection SET description = '".$link->real_escape_string($_POST['description'])."' WHERE id = 2");
}
if (!empty($_POST['userdescription'])) {
    $link->query("UPDATE firstsection SET userdescription = '".$link->real_escape_string($_POST['userdescription'])."' WHERE id = 2");
}
if (!empty($_POST['heading'])) {
    $link->query("UPDATE firstsection SET heading = '".$link->real_escape_string($_POST['heading'])."' WHERE id = 2");
}
if (!empty($_POST['subheading'])) {
    $link->query("UPDATE firstsection SET subheading = '".$link->real_escape_string($_POST['subheading'])."' WHERE id = 2");
}
if (!empty($_POST['subheading2'])) {
    $link->query("UPDATE firstsection SET subheading2 = '".$link->real_escape_string($_POST['subheading2'])."' WHERE id = 2");
}
```

In smarter version (array), you can see mr. scrowler answer. he has given you the best solution.